# wget --page-requisites locally?

Tags: html, local, wget

I have a local HTML file referencing image and style data in various places in the local file system. I’d like to get a list of all referenced files; or alternatively a command that will copy the HTML files and all referenced files to some clear location (with or without changing the links in the HTML file), so that I can make a self-contained ZIP file of the HTML page.

It seems that wget provides good support for downloading an HTML file including all prerequisites (images, styles) using the `--page-requisites` flag. Unfortunately it does not support `file://` URL.

What are my options here?

Comment: Wget does not support other than HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols.
So you have 3 options: 
1.To expose your files with FTP then load it all. 
2.To modify wget source and do the update.
3.Change the tool you are using, try http://www.httrack.com/ will it help for you idk? :)

Comment: Using a different tool is fine, as long as it is a free command-line tool for Linux, preferably packaged in Debian.

Comment: httrack might work, although it seems to insist on putting the full path to the original file in the destination path. An alternative would be `wget` with a temporary web server like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, but that is shaky due to guessing a free port and killing the web server afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Why not setting up a local Apache server and serve it off localhost?

You can use EasyPHP, MAMP or other to set up easily a local Apache server.

Comment: That would be total overkill for my use. For now I resorted to a xslt script that extract the included images, but of course it is not complete (e.g. styles, images mentioned in styles).